# JSON Read Parse Console.log returns undefined

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, undefined

this is aggravating me so much, it seems to work on everyone elses machines and in software but for some reason my node.js returns "Undefined" when I console.log the data.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./json.json', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    var config = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(config.age);

});
```

my json is

```
[
  {
    "_id": "55cff321d9ed74fcdb050680",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "11b7b82b-9e2c-44ed-a071-e9fc43f82957",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$2,888.03",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 26,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Wong Scott",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "ROBOID",
    "email": "wongscott@roboid.com",
    "phone": "+1 (932) 588-3975",
    "address": "126 Wakeman Place, Staples, Georgia, 3054",
    "about": "Non nisi in veniam irure exercitation quis ipsum voluptate. Fugiat incididunt officia enim enim in ullamco deserunt quis cupidatat anim minim ea id proident. Cillum sit voluptate Lorem incididunt ut fugiat aute occaecat mollit ullamco esse cillum. Magna duis pariatur labore ullamco laboris Lorem deserunt voluptate quis adipisicing fugiat irure. Cupidatat qui commodo adipisicing tempor. Consequat aliqua esse deserunt fugiat ut occaecat eu id id ad. Velit et dolore do culpa in laboris officia nostrud reprehenderit duis.\r\n",
    "registered": "2014-02-28T11:16:52 +05:00",
    "latitude": 45.928161,
    "longitude": 146.414649,
    "tags": [
      "proident",
      "in",
      "tempor",
      "reprehenderit",
      "dolor",
      "sit",
      "aliqua"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Golden Chase"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Yvonne Conley"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Palmer Lindsey"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Wong Scott! You have 2 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  },
  {
    "_id": "55cff321ea1689b4f93f53bb",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "5565f002-7ca7-46f5-9189-e72770bb0b02",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,160.94",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 34,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": "Waters Mcgee",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "COMVEY",
    "email": "watersmcgee@comvey.com",
    "phone": "+1 (806) 474-3083",
    "address": "817 Chester Avenue, Nanafalia, District Of Columbia, 6666",
    "about": "Aliquip dolor ut laborum Lorem ipsum deserunt tempor ullamco ut deserunt. Elit esse pariatur et ex cillum laboris culpa dolore. Laboris nulla non mollit ullamco dolore est officia laboris aliquip irure ad. Voluptate excepteur est exercitation deserunt labore eu sit reprehenderit eiusmod irure proident fugiat do.\r\n",
    "registered": "2014-04-05T10:59:32 +04:00",
    "latitude": -78.141645,
    "longitude": -178.247836,
    "tags": [
      "aute",
      "qui",
      "minim",
      "culpa",
      "laboris",
      "quis",
      "culpa"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Chan Mathews"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Tamara Drake"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Serena Villarreal"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Waters Mcgee! You have 9 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  },
  {
    "_id": "55cff3211e916e7859b4a060",
    "index": 2,
    "guid": "729c0b1a-7056-4beb-9b6c-0b08592acd50",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,204.11",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 29,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Laurel Reeves",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "SNIPS",
    "email": "laurelreeves@snips.com",
    "phone": "+1 (948) 443-2648",
    "address": "224 Thames Street, Brenton, Nebraska, 465",
    "about": "Officia Lorem nisi minim esse. Reprehenderit exercitation culpa quis Lorem sunt occaecat fugiat anim aliqua. Consectetur consequat ut proident pariatur anim anim laboris ad. Qui dolore est id tempor ex quis cillum ut incididunt amet duis magna nulla mollit. Laboris fugiat tempor laboris ullamco commodo in sint do exercitation. Quis ex eu velit quis eiusmod magna do et laborum.\r\n",
    "registered": "2015-01-13T10:16:04 +05:00",
    "latitude": -35.583701,
    "longitude": -156.036728,
    "tags": [
      "nostrud",
      "aute",
      "dolor",
      "exercitation",
      "est",
      "mollit",
      "aliqua"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Wiggins Mcdowell"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Jacobs Anderson"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Obrien Harrington"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Laurel Reeves! You have 9 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  },
  {
    "_id": "55cff3219a7d55646dca265c",
    "index": 3,
    "guid": "ba00c623-ff76-493b-96d8-d24750491f53",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,708.00",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 22,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Becker Becker",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "CEPRENE",
    "email": "beckerbecker@ceprene.com",
    "phone": "+1 (955) 554-2612",
    "address": "972 Flatlands Avenue, Sattley, Northern Mariana Islands, 5453",
    "about": "Aute consectetur dolore ex labore occaecat. Reprehenderit nulla labore sint quis aliquip. Veniam ipsum consequat incididunt ipsum sint ullamco incididunt id.\r\n",
    "registered": "2014-07-23T08:20:56 +04:00",
    "latitude": -78.745659,
    "longitude": 128.883716,
    "tags": [
      "labore",
      "culpa",
      "nostrud",
      "labore",
      "quis",
      "dolor",
      "sunt"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Brittany Tran"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Debra Nielsen"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Cheri Melendez"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Becker Becker! You have 2 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  },
  {
    "_id": "55cff3217d7d4e40c24e4094",
    "index": 4,
    "guid": "5591dee1-d6f6-4c09-925f-63c16307f4ab",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,360.06",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 31,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Wheeler Howe",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "TEMORAK",
    "email": "wheelerhowe@temorak.com",
    "phone": "+1 (969) 421-3626",
    "address": "801 Suydam Place, Glenbrook, Wyoming, 4669",
    "about": "Est mollit tempor ipsum reprehenderit dolor adipisicing quis commodo irure labore deserunt consectetur amet. Officia non qui ex nostrud do pariatur pariatur qui aliqua anim enim deserunt. Laborum consequat reprehenderit quis officia veniam adipisicing dolore veniam officia sunt. Et irure magna laborum irure occaecat commodo in irure sint sit.\r\n",
    "registered": "2014-01-30T11:14:52 +05:00",
    "latitude": -26.344453,
    "longitude": -91.688423,
    "tags": [
      "anim",
      "aute",
      "est",
      "exercitation",
      "amet",
      "dolore",
      "sit"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Flossie Bernard"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Janette Daniels"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Thomas Hoffman"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Wheeler Howe! You have 8 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "apple"
  }
]
```

Might this be a JSON issue?

Please advise.

Thank you very much!

Comment: what does `console.log(config)` output?

Comment: console.log(config) outputs the whole json file as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your json is an array of objects.

Try accessing the first element of the array and then the `age` property like this

```
console.log(config[0].age)
```

Comment: Should have simply paid more attention to the random json I picked up online for testing purposes.